# ajax call to controller function without action

Tags: ajax, controller, concrete5

I need to add a block to a page. In a block adding dialog I have a select box which I need to fill with data received from ajax prior to saving the block (it cannot be saved unless I select the option).

The problem is the ajax call is usually to a controller action which doesn't exist until I save the block which I can't save before the option is selected. How can I make an ajax call to any other non-action function prior to the block saving? Can it be any other controller function or it must only be an action_function? Is this possible?

[UPDATE]

I'm trying with routes. Declared a route in the package controller:

```
$this->app->make(Router::class)->register('/api/get_forum_posts', '\Concrete\Package\AbForum\Src\Forum\MyFunctions::get_forum_posts', null, [], [], '', [], ['GET']);
```

but it says:

> Exception Occurred:
> /srv/www/htdocs/c584/concrete/src/Controller/ApplicationAwareControllerResolver.php:89
> Class "\Concrete\Package\AbForum\Src\Forum\MyFunctions" does not
> exist.

but the class MyFunctions IS in that folder packages/ab_forum/src/Forum/MyFunctions.php

Comment: How about adding a custom route? 
https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/framework/routing/routing-basics

Comment: this is what I'm currently looking at

Comment: Does it work? If not show us, what is not working.

Comment: not yet. it says my class doesn't exist but it's there (I'll update with a code piece)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The following works.

In the package controller:

```
protected $pkgAutoloaderRegistries = [
    'src/Forum' => 'Forum'
];

public function on_start()
{
    $this->app->make(Router::class)->register('/api/get_forum_posts', 'Forum\MyFunctions::getForumPostsJson', null, [], [], '', [], ['GET']);
...
}
```

The MyFunctions controller class in packages/ab_forum/src/Forum/MyFunctions.php:

```
namespace Forum;

use Concrete\Core\Controller\AbstractController;

class MyFunctions extends AbstractController
{
    public function getForumPostsJson()
    {
        $data = $request->request->all();
        ...
        echo json_encode($json);
        exit;
    }
}
```

The block form with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo Url::to('api/get_forum_posts'); ?>',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        topic: topic.val(),
        date: date.val(),
    },
})
.done(function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: What about elaborating your answer for further readers with the class definition around the snippet (do not forget the namespace and the related use statement). An explanation of the registration parameters would be nice as too.